# Unwrapping angular mesh gives some islands distortions, why?

Tags: uv

Selected islands are skewed, mostly the one on top. My process was modeling in sketchup, then knifing it to get quads, importing to blender via skp plugin, selecting 90 edges and marking them as sharp + seams, then unwrapping. But some islands get distorted, my suspicion is on small triangles at curves that confuse blender.. what do you think? Smart UV doesn't produce distorted islands, they all are straight (but it produces more islands compared to manual unwrap).

[image: distorted islands]

Comment: You said you marked all 90-degree edges as seams. This causes each little piece surrounded by 90-degree angles to become an island. Try then *unmarking* some of the edges (ones that would make sense to share as part of a larger area) and UV-unwrap after that.